# TTStyledTextLabel - unrecognized selector exception

Tags: iphone, three20

I am using the 2.x compatible branch of Three20 library. I want to display a URL and am using the TTStyledTextLabel for this purpose.

However when trying to use it, I get an exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[TTStyledTextLabel width]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4bc440'
```

This is how I am using the TTStyledTextLabel object (inside a custom tableviewcell)

```
TTStyledTextLabel *textLabel = (TTStyledTextLabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
[textLabel setText:[TTStyledText textFromXHTML:myFormattedText lineBreaks:YES urls:YES]];
```

Can someone please tell me why this exception occurs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` member is added by the category `UIViewAdditions` on `UIView`. Can you check that it's there in this release?

Comment: Seemed to be missing there. I just replaced self.width with self.frame.size.width and this seemed to resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, caused due to the Three20 UIViewAdditions categories not being applied.

Check that you have added the -ObjC flag to your "Other Linker Flags" build. I had it missing.

There is more information on these categories not being applied on a [Three20's google groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/9a732a5aae55cbda/abdee7f0eec4cc57?lnk=gst&q=UIViewAdditions#abdee7f0eec4cc57)